# Show multiple image in gridview and then link each image from gridview that open in new tab as large individually

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I show all images in gridview in asp.net c#. And then link each image from gridview that opens in new tab as large individually.

Data type of images are varbinary(MAX).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the answer on this question:

[How can I display an image from SQL Server using ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284217/how-can-i-display-an-image-from-sql-server-using-asp-net)

Here you will see how to write the aspx file you need to display your images.

After you have done this, you could just create pretty straight forward gridview code with your images / links in it.

To make things a bit prettier, you could resize the images you show in your gridview.

http://dzone.com/snippets/c-resize-image-while